# Dijkstra Partitioning Algorithm : Special Case

Tags: algorithm, sorting, partitioning, analysis, dutch-national-flag-problem

I have been exploring Dikstra partitioning Algorithm. Below are my given:

```
R = Red
W = White 
B = Blue
```

I have this unpartitioned array.

```
| W | B  | R |  W  | R  | W | B |  W  |  W |
```

I want it partition in the format: R, W, B consecutively.

```
| R  |  ?  | W  |  B |
 0    i     j    k    n
```

Given:

```
 i = 0
 j = n
 k = n
 n = number of elements
```

Below is my algorithm:

```
 while  (i < j)
 {
     case a[i]:
         R : i++;
         W : j--; swap(a[i], a[j]);
         B : j--; k--; swap(a[i], a[k]); swap(a[i], a[j]);
     end case 
 }
 //Done Sorting
```

The output should be like this:

```
|  R  | R  | W  |  W  |  W  |   W  |  W  |  B  |  B |
```

My question are:

1. Can I reduce the number of swaps? If yes, how?
2. Is the algorithm applicable if there are 4 colors to be partitioned?

Thank you. I really need to understand this concept.

Comment: Did my post answer you? if so please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 2):

As @m69 gave the clue this is the `Dutch National Flag` problem.

Base on pseudo-code taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem):

```
A : array of values
i ← 0
j ← 0
n ← size of A - 1

while j ≤ n:
    Case A[i]:
        R:
          swap A[i] and A[j]
          i ← i + 1
          j ← j + 1
        B:
          swap A[j] and A[n]
          n ← n - 1
        W:
          j ← j + 1
```

Notice that in this case you have **1 less swap** in the B case.

For your second question: **Yes**. Easiest way to do that is to treat the 2 middle part as the same and then make another run on the array and just sort those 2.

Let say you have 4 color: `R, W, B, G` and you want to sort them in that order. So for the first step: in your switch case have `W or B:`. After finish run the algorithm run on your array and find index for the first W or B (call it i) and the index of the first G (call it j). Now all you need is to loop between `i` and `j-1` and order the W and B.

This whole process can be done in O(n).